# Can TideSDK use sqlite database on the mapped network drive?

Tags: sqlite, tidesdk

I need to create the multi-platform desktop application. And also multiple users need to work with shared data.
Since the data is corporate confidential one, I would like to put the sqlite database in the intranet.

I concern that TideSDK application locks the sqlite file on mapped network drive, then other users cannot push/pull the data anymore.

Any information will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQLite locks database files only as long as a transaction is active.

Comment: Thank you, CL. This is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

If your are flexible about database choice, you might consider running something like CouchDB or Mongo on your Intranet and make simple http requests from your app over SSL.